# INDEX + MATCH function returning wrong values

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I have a spreadsheet in Excel 2013 that uses an `INDEX` and `MATCH` function to search by an interval time (in `I4`) to pull values from the corresponding row where it is matched (in column `A`). It works as expected on all rows except three – on those problem rows it actually returns the value from the cell above.

I am using the code:

```
=INDEX(B:B, (MATCH($I$4, A:A)))
```

The value I use to search for interval time is located in cell `I4` (e.g., 10:00 AM), and the column it is matched to is `A:A`. The values I am trying to return are located in `B:B`.

The interval time column ranges from `A2`-`A37` (6:00 AM - 11:30 PM, in half-hour increments), and the values I want returned range from `B2`-`B37`.

ALL VALUES return correctly except when searching for values in `A4`, `A7`, and `A10` (7:00 AM, 8:30 AM, and 10:00 AM, respectively), which display data from the cell above the desired value (i.e., when `I4` = 7:00 AM (which equals `A4`), the formula returns the value of `B3` instead of `B4`, `I4` = 8:30 AM (`A7`) → `B6` instead of `B7`, and `I4` = 10:00 AM (`A10`) → `B9` instead of `B10`).

When I try to use an exact match:

```
=INDEX(B:B, (MATCH($I$4, A:A, 0)))
```

it returns the value #N/A for the problem rows, and correct values for only some of the others.

Any insight into what is happening?

Comment: How are the values in col A stored (time values, text, etc.)?

Comment: Both the column A values and the search value (I4) are formatted as time (ex. 8:00 AM)

Comment: I wonder if the problem is floating point rounding error.

Comment: the values I am trying to return (column B:B) are formatted as numbers with 2 decimal points. even when I use whole numbers with no decimal points it does the same thing, as well as using text - those 3 cells always return the value from the cell above

Comment: 1) The values that matter are in col A (that's what's being compared to select the row).  2) If they are stored as times, the values are stored as decimal fraction of a day and then formatted for display purposes.

Comment: Just on the off chance this is the issue... cells formatted as time may still have a date attached.  You won't see it because it's hidden, but MATCH would be affected by that.  Maybe temporarily switch the formatting to date & time to double check they're all on the same day?

Comment: I think it must be what fixer1234 said about the floating point rounding problem - what I did was format the interval time column to text (which of course changed all the values to decimal values), and just entered the interval times in again treating them as text only. Everything seems to search correctly now on all interval times. Thank you both for your input, that was driving me nuts!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that @fixer1234 is correct — it's floating point rounding error
***on the time values***.  I don't fully understand what's happening,
but I was able to reproduce it on my system, and I found a work-around: 
Change your formula to

```
=INDEX(B:B, MATCH($I$4+TIME(0,0,1), A:A))
```

This adds one second (`TIME(0,0,1)`;
the arguments are `TIME(hours,minutes,seconds)`)
to the `I4` value; that seems to be enough to get it "over the hump", so that it tests as being ≥ the value in `A4` (or `A7` or `A10`). 
BTW, I tried `TIME(0,0,0.9)`, but apparently `TIME()` won't honor fractional seconds, and so it just treats that as `TIME(0,0,0)`; i.e., just plain zero. 
If you want to get a millisecond, you can use `TIME(0,0,1)*0.001`.

P.S. You had an unnecessary pair of parentheses in your formula;
I removed it, above.

Comment: that answer works for what I need it to do, and is an easy edit to my sheets that use the formula. thank you so much!

Comment: That's a lot simpler a solution than I was coming up with.  Strange that only those three times had a problem.

Comment: @fixer1234: Yeah; as I said, I don't fully understand what's happening.  `$I$4<A7` evaluates to `FALSE`, `$I$4=A7` evaluates to `TRUE`, and `$I$4-A7` evaluates to 0,

Comment: @fixer1234: Congratulations on joining Club 5000.